# Custom next/previous arrow buttons of the slider component of the jQuery plugin fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I was working with the jQuery plugin fullPage.js. The slider component implements two arrows as the next/previous button that I need to change with a custom button, specifically an image.

I have analyzed at the CSS file of the plugin but considering that actually I'm not an expert of html/css code and the functions of the buttons seem do not use images for the latters, I'm not able to do the modification.

Has anyone a solution?

The link of the fullPage.js GitHub repository: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your image size is 50x90 pixels...

```
.fp-controlArrow .fp-next,
.fp-controlArrow .fp-prev {
   border: none;
   width: 50px;
   height: 90px;
}
.fp-controlArrow .fp-prev {
    background: url("/path/to/image-prev.png");
}
.fp-controlArrow .fp-next {
    background: url("/path/to/image-next.png");
}
```

Comment: Thanks fort the reply. I have tried it substituting the original code in the CSS of the plugin but seems not work. I have noticed that the div linked with a slide and containing the control disappears setting the border in none.

Comment: Perhaps you could assemble a working demo on http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem and collaborate on a solution.

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage - Here is the demo and you can see the arrows. If you analyze the page with the inspector you are able to see that the divs containing the arrows are are respectively "fp-controlArrow fp-prev" and "fp-controlArrow fp-next". Changing in the CSS of the plugin, the border from solid to none, the entire divs disappear.

Comment: Did you also add the explicit `width` and `height` as in my example above? Set to the size of the image you're linking to?

Comment: Yes, I have specified the dimensions.